# Paypal Express check out issue in live server

Tags: .net, paypal, live, express-checkout

Am using PayPalCoreSDK , PayPalMerchantSDK.dll and PayPalPermissionsSDK.dll version 1.7.1 for express checkout payment with trail. Everything goes fine in localhost with sandbox credentials but now am moving the same code to live server with the same sandbox credentials am not redirecting to pay pal site the error am getting is Invalid HTTP response The underlying connection was closed: An un [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJfMR.png)expected error occurred on a send. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your new server is not using the TLS 1.2 protocol to send HTTP requests to PayPal, which is now required in the sandbox (and will be on the live servers next year).

I'm not as familiar with .NET as I am PHP, so I can't provide direct info like I typically would when people bring this up, but you just need to make sure your server is sending all requests over the TLS 1.2 protocol and the connection failure should go away.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Actually we are using windows server 2008 and by default it will support TLS 1.2 protocol but not with.net framework 4.5. The problem was with .net framework. TLS 1.2 protocol is supported in .net framework 4.5 and we upgraded to 4.5 and it is working fine.